# How to use TestStack.White to simulate click on a dynamic MenuItem in WPF?

Tags: wpf, automated-tests, teststack

I'm trying to use TestStack.White to simulate a click on a menu subitem in a WPF application. That subitem is added at runtime, and I have little control over how it's created. I don't seem to be able to find the menu subitem to click.

I have tried this:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem x:Name="MainMenu" Header="Menu">
                <MenuItem x:Name="SubMenu" Header="Sub Menu"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var newItem = new MenuItem();
            newItem.Header = string.Format("Item {0}", i + 1);
            newItem.Name = string.Format("Item{0}", i + 1);
            this.SubMenu.Items.Add(newItem);
            newItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MenuItemClickHandler); 
        }
    }

    private void MenuItemClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
        MessageBox.Show(this, "You clicked " + menuItem.Header, "Menu Click", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
}
```

**ConsoleApplication1.Program**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"C:\{path}\WpfApplication3\bin\Debug";
        string prog = Path.Combine(path, "WpfApplication3.exe");

        TestStack.White.Application app = TestStack.White.Application.Launch(prog);
        var window = app.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByText("MainWindow"), InitializeOption.WithCache);
        window.WaitWhileBusy();

        var menu = window.MenuBar.MenuItem("Menu", "SubMenu", "Item2");
        menu.Click();
    }
}
```

I'm unsure how to find the menu subitems, and I'm guessing its because they weren't there when the application was compiled ?

*Apologies for the Noddy example, but WPF isn't my forte, and neither is TestStack.White*

Answer (score 0):

Here's where I got to *(which works)*, but why are the added menu items "ChildMenus", and not findable in the same way the "menu" and "sub menu" are found ? Also, why is the child menu found by a name of "item 2" *(and not, as I thought would be the case, of "item2")* ? Why the apparent mix up of "name" and "header" used in the xaml ?

```
    //var menu = window.MenuBar.MenuItem("Menu", "SubMenu", "Item2");

    var menu = window.MenuBar.MenuItem("Menu", "Sub Menu");
    var menus = menu.ChildMenus;
    menu = menus.First(m => m.Name == "Item 2");

    menu.Click();
```